# Getting most recent observation & date from several columns

Tags: python, pandas

Take the following toy DataFrame:

```
data = np.arange(35, dtype=np.float32).reshape(7, 5)
data = pd.concat((
    pd.DataFrame(list('abcdefg'), columns=['field1']),
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['field2', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'])),
    axis=1)

data.iloc[1:4, 4:] = np.nan
data.iloc[4, 3:] = np.nan

print(data)
  field1  field2  2014  2015  2016  2017
0      a     0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1      b     5.0   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
2      c    10.0  11.0  12.0   NaN   NaN
3      d    15.0  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
4      e    20.0  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
5      f    25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0
6      g    30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0
```

I'd like to **replace the "year" columns (2014-2017) with two fields: the most recent non-null observation, and the corresponding year of that observation**.  Assume `field1` is a unique key. (I'm not looking to do any groupby ops, just 1 row per record.)  I.e.:

```
  field1  field2   obs  date
0      a     0.0   4.0  2017
1      b     5.0   7.0  2015
2      c    10.0  12.0  2015
3      d    15.0  17.0  2015
4      e    20.0  21.0  2014
5      f    25.0  29.0  2017
6      g    30.0  34.0  2017
```

I've gotten this far:

```
pd.melt(data, id_vars=['field1', 'field2'], 
        value_vars=['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'])\
    .dropna(subset=['value'])

   field1  field2 variable  value
0       a     0.0     2014    1.0
1       b     5.0     2014    6.0
2       c    10.0     2014   11.0
3       d    15.0     2014   16.0
4       e    20.0     2014   21.0
5       f    25.0     2014   26.0
6       g    30.0     2014   31.0
# ...
```

But am struggling with how to pivot back to desired format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
d2 = data.melt(id_vars=["field1", "field2"], var_name="date", value_name="obs").dropna(subset=["obs"])
d2["date"] = d2["date"].astype(int)
df = d2.loc[d2.groupby(["field1", "field2"])["date"].idxmax()]
```

which gives me

```
   field1  field2  date   obs
21      a     0.0  2017   4.0
8       b     5.0  2015   7.0
9       c    10.0  2015  12.0
10      d    15.0  2015  17.0
4       e    20.0  2014  21.0
26      f    25.0  2017  29.0
27      g    30.0  2017  34.0
```

Answer (score 3):

what about the following apporach:

```
In [160]: df
Out[160]:
  field1  field2  2014  2015  2016  2017
0      a     0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0 -10.0
1      b     5.0   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
2      c    10.0  11.0  12.0   NaN   NaN
3      d    15.0  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN
4      e    20.0  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
5      f    25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0
6      g    30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0

In [180]: df.groupby(lambda x: 'obs' if x.isdigit() else x, axis=1) \
     ...:   .last() \
     ...:   .assign(date=df.filter(regex='^\d{4}').loc[:, ::-1].notnull().idxmax(1))
Out[180]:
  field1  field2   obs  date
0      a     0.0 -10.0  2017
1      b     5.0   7.0  2015
2      c    10.0  12.0  2015
3      d    15.0  17.0  2015
4      e    20.0  21.0  2014
5      f    25.0  29.0  2017
6      g    30.0  34.0  2017
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this one -- IIUC, the OP wants the most recent valid value, not the maximum.  In the given dataset, they're the same, but if (e.g.) a for 2017 was -10, I think that's what we should return.

Comment: @DSM, thank you for the clarification! I think if i will replace `max()` with `last()` it'll do the trick...

Comment: But now you're using the last _obs_ but the maximum _date_ (so 2016, not 2017).  [To clarify, I mean "the date at which the maximum is reached", I'm just lazy to the point of being wrong.]  You need the equivalent of `idxlast()` (which doesn't exist, but YKWIM.)

Answer (score 2):

`last_valid_index` + `agg('last')`

```
A=data.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x : x.last_valid_index(),1)
B=data.groupby(['value'] * data.shape[1], 1).agg('last')
data['date']=A
data['obs']=B

data
Out[1326]: 
  field1  field2  2014  2015  2016  2017  date   obs
0      a     0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0  2017   4.0
1      b     5.0   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN  2015   7.0
2      c    10.0  11.0  12.0   NaN   NaN  2015  12.0
3      d    15.0  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN  2015  17.0
4      e    20.0  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  2014  21.0
5      f    25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  2017  29.0
6      g    30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  2017  34.0
```

---

By using `assign` we can push them into one line as blow

```
data.assign(date=data.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x : x.last_valid_index(),1),obs=data.groupby(['value'] * data.shape[1], 1).agg('last'))
Out[1340]: 
  field1  field2  2014  2015  2016  2017  date   obs
0      a     0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0  2017   4.0
1      b     5.0   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN  2015   7.0
2      c    10.0  11.0  12.0   NaN   NaN  2015  12.0
3      d    15.0  16.0  17.0   NaN   NaN  2015  17.0
4      e    20.0  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  2014  21.0
5      f    25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  2017  29.0
6      g    30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  2017  34.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Also another possibility by using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
data.melt(id_vars=["field1", "field2"], var_name="date", 
          value_name="obs")\
    .dropna(subset=['obs'])\
    .sort_values(['field1', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])\
    .drop_duplicates('field1', keep='first')
```

which gives you

```
   field1  field2  date   obs
21      a     0.0  2017   4.0
8       b     5.0  2015   7.0
9       c    10.0  2015  12.0
10      d    15.0  2015  17.0
4       e    20.0  2014  21.0
26      f    25.0  2017  29.0
27      g    30.0  2017  34.0
```

Comment: @bradsolomon, life is always better with options